# wopen calls when porting to Linux

Tags: c++

I have an application which was developed under Windows, but for gcc. The code is mostly OS-independent, with very few classes which are Windows specific because a Linux port was always regarded as necessary.

The API, especially that which gets called as a direct result of user interaction, is using wide char arrays instead of char arrays (as a side note, I cannot change the API itself - at this point, std::wstring cannot be used). These are considered as encoded in UTF-16.

In some places, the code opens files, mostly using the windows-specific `_wopen` function call. The problem with this is there is no `wopen`-like substitute for Linux because Linux "only deals with bytes".

The question is: how do I port this code ? What if I wanted to open a file with the name "something™.log", how would I go about doing so in Linux ? Is a cast to char* sufficient, would the wide chars be picked up automatically based on the locale (probably not) ? Do I need to convert manually ? I'm a bit confused regarding this, perhaps someone could point me to some documentation regarding the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy I took on Mac hinges on the fact that Mac OS X uses utf-8 in all its file io POSIX api's.

I thus created a type "fschar" thats a char in windows non unicode builds, wchar_t in windows UNICODE builds and char (again) when building for Mac OS.

I pass around all file system strings using this type. String literals are encoded with wrappers (TEXT("literal")) to get the correct encoding - all my data files store utf-8 characters on disk that, on windows UNICODE builds, I MultiByteToWideChar to convert to utf16.

Answer (score 0):

Linux does not support UTF16 filenames. It does however support UTF8 files and those can be opened using plain old `fopen()`.
What you should do is convert you wide strings to UTF8.